# Variable number of arguments to constructor with variable types creating variable private member in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, instance-variables

I have really heavy task to achieve and I haven't found any solution good enough. So, here is the description:
- task is to evaluate multiple single dimension arrays which number can vary
- good news is that it is possible to specify types of arrays

And desirable way of doing it:
- creating a class with constructor that accepts variable number of arrays
- these arrays should be also used as properties (private members), so multiple operations can be done on(with) them during lifecycle of object

How I tried to do it:
- constructor member function with variable number of paramaters (I'm not sure why this doesn't work)
- constructor with vector should be better way, but how to store arrays that type is specified in separate array, meaning you can't expect certain datatype for certain array in advance
- I tried to declare variable number of arrays as private members with preprocessor, but it seems loops and other code do not work well inside private: declaration

Any idea from anybody?

Comment: Could you show us "some" of your code attempts ? Given that you want type-polymorphism, it seems you'll need to use either inheritance or templates, but it's hard to tell at a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> constructor that accepts variable number of arrays:

```
vector< vector<T> > ?
```

the inner vectors can be of different sizes but must be of the same type.

> constructor member function with variable number of parameters

You can use a function with variable number of parameters that creates a class, look at how boost::bind works, that takes lots of different parameter lists.

boost mpl may answer what you are trying to do, although it is rather unclear.

Comment: Thanks, @CashCow. I know about inner vectors, I haven't point this out, though. However, This describes part of my problems: my inner vectors would be of different type.

Comment: I also need to go more in-depth with constructor to see, why it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks a fair bit like you are trying to implement a tabular data set. Are all your vectors the same length an represent columns of such a data set?

Comment: Yes, they are. I am talking about dataset, grid.

Comment: I am very very experienced with these, having worked on both TDS at a certain famous bank and on Blotter at a company that manages deal capture transfer between famous banks. You will find you need some kind of variant class, but for efficiency handle macro-column operations, i.e. you deal with variant collection types, not collections of variants.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple parametrized class ?

If your compiler support C++0x you can also use initializer list for constructors with variable number of paramaters.

```
template<class ArrayType>
class ArrayContainer
{
   std::vector<ArrayType> m_arrays;

   public:
   ArrayContainer(std::initializer_list<ArrayType> arrays)
   {
     m_arrays.reserve(arrays.size());
     std::copy(arrays.begin(), arrays.end(), m_array);
   }
};
```

The constructor now accepts variable number of arrays.

```
auto container = new ArrayContainer({ a, b, c });
```